# Collecting data from web in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, web

I have to handle a project at college and my idea is to write a desktop application that searches the web for data and store the results in a txt file. For example:

User would enter 5 cities and the app would search the web for the temperatures high and low for that day.

What sort of technologies would I have to use?

Comment: You should pay more attention in class? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. find a web api/service that you could access to get the temperature information that you are after. i.e. [Weather API from
   OpenWeatherMap](https://openweathermap.org/api)
2. invoke the api/service based on the instruction accordingly to get the data. i.e.[Calling a Web API From a .NET Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)
3. store the data to file. i.e. [How to: Write to a Text File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

You should consinder looking at the following:
[Weather API](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2016/05/get-weather-forecast-data-c/)